# In R, how to multiply 2 matrices while offsetting by 1 row?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to adapt my mindset from Excel. Say I have these 2 matrices:

[image]

I would like to multiply the last 2 columns of each matrix by each other, but the 1st row of matrix1 by the 2nd row of matrix 2, the 2nd row of matrix 2 by the 3rd row of matrix 3, etc., as shown below:

[image]

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: `matrix2[-1,] * matrix1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix1[,2]*matrix2[2:4,2]

matrix1[,2]*matrix2[2:(dim(matrix2)[1]),2]


[1]  40 100 180
```

Comment: It's easier to just do `matrix2[-1, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

With data:

```r
df1 <- matrix(1:6, 3)
df2 <- matrix(c(1:4, seq(0, 30, 10)), 4)
```

We can do:

```r
df1 * tail(df2, -1)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[2,]    2   40
#[3,]    6  100
#[4,]   12  180
```

The `tail` function grabs the end of a vector. If we specify `-1`, it will grab everything except for the first row.